# Mysql Table Optimization For Filtering and preventing filesort

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, postgresql

I am building an angular quiz app with nodejs mysql as backend. The Quiz question table has fields like id,title,choice_a,choice_b..choice_d,subject_id fk,topic_id fk,rand1,rand2,rand3

the ordering is either id asc,id desc,rand1 asc,rand1 desc,rand2 asc,rand2 desc,rand3 asc,rand3 desc etc to randomize the order

The rand fields contain values from 1 - 20 assigned randomly to give random quiz

My question is for a query like given below

```
    SELECT question.*,subject.title as subject_title,region.title as region_title,topic.title as topic_title FROM question LEFT JOIN subject ON
   (question.subject_id = subject.id) LEFT JOIN region ON (question.region_id = region.id) LEFT JOIN topic ON (question.topic_id = 
   topic.id) WHERE ((question.subject_id = '4')) ORDER BY rand1 DESC LIMIT 20
```

here the results are filtered using rand1(assigned randomly). Now i want to know if adding a combined index for (subject_id,rand1) will help?

If it does then i will have to add combined indexes for  (subject_id,rand1)
(subject_id,rand2)
(subject_id,rand3)
 (subject_id,id)
right since they are commonly used filtering + ordering combination?

Does using postgresql instead of mysql helps in this case?

What is the maximum number of fields in a composite index?

Comment: Questions 1 and 2: why don't you try these out and see for yourself? Explain select... will also help. 3: You cannot possibly expect anyone to answer this for you based on a single query. 4: 16 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the answer. By creating different composite indexes i was able to increase the request per second of node server to more than twice. The composite indexes were many to precisely optimize frequent queries. By benchmarking the query before and after adding the index I was able to optimize the most. 
Thank you everyone....